# How to write a SQL query for multiple tables without join

Tags: sql

I have a database with ~ 1000 tables where each table has the column `date`.
I want to see how many tables are between the date 2000 and 2016.

Each table is a company name, so that I get all the companies funded between 2000 and 2016 I would need this query.

I tried it with something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM date 
WHERE date BETWEEN 2000 AND 2020;
```

but the problem is, that I need to do it for all ~ 1000 tables.

Is there a way to write an easy loop for a SQL query?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your problem is the data model. You shouldn't have one table per company, but only one table instead containing a company ID. Then there would be no problem to get what you want. As is, you may want to try dynamic SQL. This means you query the system tables to get all table names you are interested in. Then you have your app write a query for each table and run these. What is your DBMS?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thats totally true but I didn't do the `database` so I can only use what's availible unluckily.

Comment: This requires dynamic SQL, which depends on the particular database.  However, I would talk to whoever owns the database and strongly suggest that they change the data model or at least maintain a view that combines all the tables together.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT CompanyName FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT CompanyName FROM table2
)
WHERE date BETWEEN 2000 AND 2020
```

and dynamic query is below. You will keep all your table names in "yourTable".

```
Declare @ID int,
Declare @tableName varchar(50) 
Set @ID =1

While Exists(select * from yourTable where ID <=1000)
BEGIN
    Set @tableName = (Select tableName from yourTable where ID = @ID)

    Select CompanyName from @tableName 
    Where
    date BETWEEN 2000 AND 2020
    + ' UNION ALL '
    
    Set @ID = @ID +1

END
```

Comment: For which DBMS is this? How can you restrict the date in your first query when you are only selecting company names? And as to the script: Which DBMS allows a variable table name? And where does `yourTable` come from that contains all the table names? And a date between 2000 and 2020? You mean a year? This all looks very wrong.

Comment: first of all if you are using sql query, if there is a date column you don't have to select it with using SQL. Secondly you will keep all table names in a yourTable and I wrote it. In my example every table has a date column.

Comment: I suppose you want the query to look something like this: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT CompanyName, date FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT CompanyName, date FROM table2 ...) WHERE date >= DATE '2000-01-01' AND date <'2021-01-01'`. As to `yourTable`: I see that you added a remark to your answer. But every DBMS has system tables already, so we can probably use them instead. Then, the OP hasn't specified which DBMS, but you are suggesting a script of a certain syntax. To which DBMS does this syntax belong?

Comment: Of course Sql, if do you want to improve my sql query, I would be happy, you can edit.